# Alternative method to get EWS api?

Tags: exchangewebservices

GPO and the will of the Gods dictates that I can't use Nuget to grab the managed API. Is there an alternative source? If I simply pull the entire github branch, how do I compile and install it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an alternative source?

You can download it directly from Microsoft from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951).

Once you install it, you can from visual studio add a reference to the DLL that was installed to the installation folder.